# Simulate Location bt available on 2nd run

Tags: ios, swift, gpx

[image: Simulate Location button]

Is it just a little Xcode bug or it's only me who has to run a project two times to be able to simulate location?

Comment: You can set location on simulator -> Debug option -> Location -> Custom location And also edit schema -> option there is option to simulate location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best option to use location for test in xcode is add **.gpx** as belove:

[image]

And set the name of that filed for example `customlocation` so it will be appear like this `customlocation.gpx`.

After that just add your custom location in side the file like following:

[image]

So after that when you sun the project you can find that run time location at location bar of `xcode` select once and you dont need to enable it again and again and its a good way to use custom location.

That will be selected like this once you does that check mark:

[image]

Comment: That's some useful info, thanks. Good to know that I only need to Simulate once. Used to click that every time I run the project.